# WinRT Reflection (C++/CX)

Tags: reflection, windows-runtime, introspection, c++-cx

how can I introspect an object in C++/CX? I known how to get its class name (using IInspectable) but I wasn't able to figure out how to get a list of its properties or how to invoke methods if I have just a name of the method (string). I searched for an answer here and at Google but what I found is related to the .NET layer of WinRT (the System.Reflection namespace doesn't seem to be available in C++/CX).

Comment: Nothing under the System namespace is going to be available from C++/CX. All of that is .Net-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ doesn't provide any specific APIs to reflect on WinRT types, these types are fully defined in CX compliant metadata files and you can use the CLR native metadata APIs to read their definition.  There is a snippet at

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/211ef583-db11-4e55-926b-6d9ab53dbdb4/ccx-reflection

James McNellis released a full C++ library for CX reflection last year

http://seaplusplus.com/2012/04/26/cxxreflect-native-reflection-for-the-windows-runtime/

Answer (score 6):

As hinted by svick, you take the class name (retrieved from IInspectable::GetRuntimeClassName), hand it to RoGetMetaDataFile.  This returns an [IMetaDataImport2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms232953.aspx).  Now call [IMetaDataImport2::FindTypeDefByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233290.aspx).  This returns a typedef token.  Now call [IMetaDataImport2::GetTypeDefProps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230143.aspx) which will give you properties about the type.

From the typedef properties, you can retrieve other information - enumerate the methods/fields if it's an interface/struct (or enum), find the type of the runtime class (if it's an interface or a class), etc.

Comment: I had tried using RoGetMetaDataFile before I posted the question here, it doesn't work (doesn't find the type as returned by GetRuntimeClassName).

Comment: What was the string returned by GetRuntimeClassName?  And what error was returned?  What are the parameters you're passing to RoGetMetaDataFile?

Comment: Instead of calling `FindTypeDefByName`, can one just use the `mdTypeDef` returned by `RoGetMetaDataFile` via its last out parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Even most of the normal .Net reflection isn't included in the subset of .Net available to WinRT applications. And I didn't find any reflection-related types in the [WinRT documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx). This means that (unless I overlooked something) reflection is simply not exposed by the available APIs.

Although I don't see why it shouldn't be available. The metadata is there, which should be enough.

When looking at the C++-specific functions, there is the function [`RoGetMetaDataFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229856.aspx). It seems it should be possible to use it to get the metadata. But it's a native C++ function, not C++/CX. This means it's not easy to use (manual memory management, …) and I doubt it will be allowed in apps that are in the Store.

Comment: Fairly sure it is in fact RoGetMetaDataFile() to get a IMetaDataImport2 interface pointer.  It being a native function is not an issue, C++/CX generates native code.

Comment: There's no reason for object introspection not to be allowed in apps in the app store. Apple does allow it.

Comment: As for RoGetMetaDataFile I was able to use it with classes from external components (I've created a DLL in another project) but not with classes from the same project where I call RoGetMetaDataFile. I don't think this is intended behavior, apparently I'm using RoGetMetaDataFile incorrectly or it's a bug in the early preview.

Comment: @Atamiri, I don't know the reason. But I think the fact that .Net reflection is almost non-existent in the WinRT subset of .Net says something.

Comment: @svick, .NET reflection *is* available in Metro style apps. The trick is the GetTypeInfo() extension method from the System.Reflection namespace. It is invoked on a Type object and returns a TypeInfo object that contains the missing reflection APIs.